# What startSetup() and endSetup() methods actually does?

Tags: magento2

I'm confused on what those 2 methods does. I have a code like:

```
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $setup->startSetup();

    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    ...
    ...
    $setup->endSetup();
}
```

**Could someone explain that to me?**

**why do I need to call a function from an interface?**

**What's the purpose of it?**

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see, it just setting additional settings before you starting setup:

> Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql

```
/**
 * Run additional environment before setup
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function startSetup()
{
    $this->rawQuery("SET SQL_MODE=''");
    $this->rawQuery("SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0");
    $this->rawQuery("SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'");

    return $this;
}
```

and than reverts it back:

```
/**
 * Run additional environment after setup
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function endSetup()
{
    $this->rawQuery("SET SQL_MODE=IFNULL(@OLD_SQL_MODE,'')");
    $this->rawQuery("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=IF(@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0, 0, 1)");

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you also tell me how $setup->startSetup(); reaches it's function if I'm calling an interface function? I really don't get it... :(

Comment: @HELPME If you are using an interfaces in the `__construct` method the dependency injection works. It uses the `ObjectManager` class to locate corresponding class (for the specified interface) and adding this class.

Comment: And if I'm not using an interface in my `__construct` method? I have only `eavSetupFactory`, here..

Comment: @HELPME You can obtain more info by inspecting the `Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager` class code. Specially the code of the methods `create` and `get`

Comment: @HELPME The `install` method of your module with all arguments has been called from the core magento installer, where this interface was specified in the constructor. By this way you can use the `interface` as an object in you code.

Comment: Could you tell me where can I find that `core magento installer` directory? I want to see if this interface is specified in the constructor. Because in my `install()` method I have `ModuleSetupData` interface, which extends `SetupInterface`. I found that first mentioned interface is defined in the root di.xml file and it has a preference for DataSetup class. But I can't find anything about `SetupInterface`.

Comment: @HELPME Take a look at the setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php line ~868 (`$installer->install($setup, $moduleContextList[$moduleName]);`)

Comment: @HELPME the corresponding class for the `SetupInterface` is `Magento\Setup\Module\Setup`

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please answer one more question in a chat?